# Can you debug interactively in Workflow?

Tags: ios, automation

I’ve been creating some mobile workflows, and debugging has become a bit of a chore. My current method of doing so has simply been to add a **Quick Look** and **Exit Workflow** step. Since Workflow execution often runs way too quickly for me to see the evaluation path, especially when `If` branches and `Repeat` sections are in use.

[image: Workflow creation screenshot showing a Repeat, Quick Look, and Exit Workflow steps, among others]

Is there a better method for debugging, perhaps a step-wise debugger (ala. `perl-d`, Ruby’s `byebug` or `pry`, `gdb`, etc.) with the ability to investigate data at each step?

Answer (score 1):

No. Since the workflow team and app are now Apple employees and Apple first party app, I would expect this to feature to come to either playgrounds or Xcode if it’s not added to whatever becomes of the app itself. Siri automations are going to need this debugging as well but I expect one to three years for this to arrive on a form we will all see and be able to use.